# Error on push after unsetting upstream

Tags: git

I have a local branch named `topic1`, branched off `origin/master`.

I set `origin/master` as my upstream for `topic1` so that my `git pull --rebase` will allow me to quickly and easily rebase onto `origin/master`.

Now my `topic1` branch is getting sufficiently large and is becoming more long-term, so I want to push it to `origin` as `origin/VER_1_0_0_Topic1` (different name from local). I performed these steps:

```
git checkout topic1
git branch --unset-upstream
git push -u origin VER_1_0_0_Topic1
```

After my `git push` command I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec VER_1_0_0_Topic1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'C:/Repositories/my_repo.git'
```

Any reason why this isn't working? All of the Googling I've done on this error says that I'm attempting to push a branch with no commits, but that's certainly not the case (there are lots of commits on `topic1`.

Note that for any other local branch that has *never* had its upstream set before, the same push command works without error. So there must be some left-over metadata regarding `topic1`'s upstream branch that is causing this to fail (that's my assumption, at least).

Using Git 1.9.0 on Windows using msysgit. My `push.default` is set to `upstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the local branch name like this:

```
git push -u origin topic1:VER_1_0_0_Topic1
```

The name before the `:` is the local name and the name after the `:` is the name you wish to push to on the remote.  Incidentally this will work regardless of what the upstream is set to, so there is no need to unset it.

Comment: Why is this necessary? Can't it deduce the source branch based on the currently checked out branch? Also as I said, in most other cases it's able to correctly assume that my current branch is the source for some reason. Is this only a problem is src and dst branches do not have identical names?

Comment: @RobertDailey Probably because it's a bit ambiguous in this case.  What you're asking for would entail pushing the current treeish to whatever name is provided to push whenever that name did not specify a local branch.  This would mean that whenever you have a typo in the argument to push you would wind up pushing whatever is currently checked out to a remote branch with that name.  It's not so much not possible as not desirable.